# Determining the Password Status of a User

Tags: debian, ssh, password

I have a debian box that I connect to via SSH. I have removed the password from the users `root`, and my personal account using the instructions [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-delete-user-password/), and set up a public/private key pair so I can log in, but only if I have the private key.

I recently ran `cat /etc/passwd` in order to see what other users where on the system, and got a fair list back. So, how can I determine the password status for each user so that if I make the box public to the wider world (via ssh only), there are no other users that someone could use to authenticate with?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably you should look at sshd configuration.

There is an option to deny password authentication:

```
PasswordAuthentication no
```

and you can create a list of users that are allowed to connect via ssh:

```
AllowUsers cgoddard
```

Answer (score 2):

The "fair list" of users you get back are probably just system users, i.e., users created to own some service (having e.g. apache running as a separate user helps limiting the damage it could do to others if it goes crazy or is subverted). They probably have impossible passwords (here in Fedora 18 I have for example in `/etc/shadow` the entry `bin:*:15209:0:99999:7:::`, as `*` is not the hash of any password, there is no way to log in as user `bin`; note that `/etc/shadow` is root-only read for security reasons).